# If I do not use React Developer Tools or put console.log() in code, is there any way to show values of "this.props" on "Console" tab of the browser?

Tags: reactjs, browser, react-redux

As the title, I would like to find out the way to print values of "this.props" of a Component in React.

In a normal way, we can put console.log() in code or use React Developer Tools by click on "React" tab after open "F12 on browser" and use "$r" on "Console" tab to print "props". But, how could I print "this.props" without React Developer Tools or console.log() in code? Is there any global default variable that contains props of React? I have tried to use $('classID').... to find out props but it also only appear React value after I click on React Developer Tools.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
console.log(this.props)
```

before you return JSX

Comment: Thank you. But, I mean I could not edit the code to print console.log(). I just edited the description.